MYSQL - Using MAX or COUNT in SELECT for INSERT and Have MAX/COUNT change for each INSERT
I am using the sample Northwind DB and would like to INSERT a new product for every discontinued product and renaming the new product with an appended '_v2'. Problem is I would like to specify a new ProductID (for a table that would not have ProductID as autoIncrement). How can I have it get the largest ProductID number and increment it.
I tried this:
INSERT INTO `products2`( `ProductName`, `ProductID`, `SupplierID`, `CategoryID`, `QuantityPerUnit`, `UnitPrice`, `UnitsInStock`, `UnitsOnOrder`, `ReorderLevel`, `Discontinued`) 
SELECT CONCAT(p.ProductName, '_V2'), (SELECT MAX(p2.ProductID) FROM products2 p2) + p.ProductID, p.SupplierID, p.CategoryID, 30, p.UnitPrice * 2, 10, 20, 2, 'n' 
FROM products2 p 
WHERE p.Discontinued = 'y';

and problem is it seems to retrieve the the MAX productID and reusing it over and over again, giving all my new products the same MAX + 1 productID (I tested it with removing ProductID as a Primary Key) I even tried this with the same result:
INSERT INTO `products2`( `ProductName`, `ProductID`, `SupplierID`, `CategoryID`, `QuantityPerUnit`, `UnitPrice`, `UnitsInStock`, `UnitsOnOrder`, `ReorderLevel`, `Discontinued`) 
SELECT CONCAT(p.ProductName, '_V2'), (SELECT x.ProductID FROM (SELECT p.ProductID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ProductID DESC) AS rank FROM products2 p) AS x WHERE x.rank = 1) +1, p.SupplierID,p.CategoryID, 30, p.UnitPrice * 2, 10, 20, 2, 'n' 
FROM products2 p 
WHERE p.Discontinued = 'y';

I can't get the Subquery to be re-run per Insert

With MySQL 8 CTE and ROW_NUMBER was introduced, so use thm like
create table product (
id int,
name varchar(20),
discontinued bit(1)
);

insert into product values (1, 'prod1', false), (2, 'prod2', true), (3, 'prod3', true);


Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


insert into product (id, name, discontinued)
  WITH CTE As (select max(id) as max_id from product)
  
select max_id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER  BY id) as  newId
  , concat(p.name, '_v2') newProd, false as discontinued
FROM product p CROSS JOIN CTE
WHERE discontinued = 1



Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


SELECT * FROM product




id
name
discontinued




1
prod1
0


2
prod2
1


3
prod3
1


4
prod2_v2
0


5
prod3_v2
0



fiddle

Could do with a discontinued test (prod1 is not discontinued) and new versions should have discontinued set to false.

yes, i wanted only to show how it could be done, because, the prior answer seems to much antiquated

Note: This answer is an old way of solving such problem and it might get discontinued. So if you are on MySQL 8+ please use the answer provided by nbk
You can tweak your query to assign the max(ProductID) in a subquery to a variable and then increment your variable within your query.
Here is a simplified way that you can use on your problem:
create table product (
id int,
name varchar(20),
discontinued bit(1)
);

insert into product values 
(1, 'prod1', false),
(2, 'prod2', true),
(3, 'prod3', true);

insert into product (id, name, discontinued)
select @max:=@max+1 newId, concat(p.name, '_v2') newProd, true as discontinued
  from (select @max:=max(id) from product) mx,
       product p
 where p.discontinued = 1;
 
select * from product;

See it working here

That is a bad idea, as it is old style and could be deprecated in future. Using a cute or window functions woul es be a better chouce

@nbk Thanks. I'm still actively working on mysql 5.7 so guess im too use to it. I will add a note on the answer to state it is an old way of achieving it. Cheers.
